# UITableView/ListView iOS versus Android

Tags: android, iphone, uitableview, listview

On UITableView of iOS there is an UItableview cell that display use a xib file that able to display the text, along with the small picture icon.

I would like to do the same with ListView with android, right now I see most examples in android only listed the the text with no picture icon.

I am looking for example in android that accomplished with the UITableViewcell with xib file in iOS.

Comment: it doesn't get better than that. right on.. don't like it .. booyah...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a ListView with icons:

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/